# Can I apply linseed oil paint to new, primed timber?

Tags: wood, paint

We've recently had some new wooden casement windows installed. They arrived having already had a coat of (what I assume is) primer applied. Here's a close-up:

[image: Close-up of new window]

The windows were made and installed by a local joiner who was recommended to us.

Since the old windows needed replacement due to rot, earlier than their expected lifespan, he has advised us to paint the new ones with linseed oil paint.

However, the research I've done seems to suggest that you'd normally want to apply linseed oil paints directly to the timber. The only references I can see to priming are about using some heated/diluted volume of the same paint as a mist coat. No-one seems to suggest applying linseed oil paint to a previously primed surface.

I'm conscious that I'm an amateur and our joiner is a respected professional, so I'm just hoping to get a second opinion please. Will we have any issues if we apply linseed oil paint to wood that has already been primed?

Comment: The Purpose of linseed oil is to soak into the wood and form a protective coating (when reacting with air)..  That Primer will not allow the oil to penetrate into the wood hence will just sit on top of the paint layer and contaminate your painting surface.  IMHO -- just paint over with a good oil based paint.

Comment: Have you expressed your concerns to your window builder to see what he says? Does he offer any sort of warranty on the windows? If so, better follow his directions to ensure he'll honor it should something go wrong. Also, you may want to check out [woodworking.se] for lots of finishing tips, including linseed oil.